# script to run a certain program with input from a given directory

Tags: testing, maven, for-loop, sh

So I need to run a bunch of (maven) tests with testfiles being supplied as an argument to a maven task.

Something like this:

`mvn clean test -Dtest=<filename>`

And the test files are usually organized into different directories. So I'm trying to write a script which would execute the above 'command' and automatically feed the name of all files in a given dir to the `-Dtest`.

So I started out with a shellscript called 'run_test':

```
#!/bin/sh
if test $# -lt 2; then
    echo "$0: insufficient arguments on the command line." >&1
    echo "usage: $0 run_test dirctory" >&1
    exit 1
fi
for file in allFiles <<<<<<< what should I put here? Can I somehow iterate thru the list of all files' name in the given directory put the file name here?
     do mvn clean test -Dtest= $file  

exit $?
```

The part where I got stuck is how to get a list of filenames. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$1` contains the directory name (validation of the user input is a separate issue), then

```
for file in $1/*
do
    [[ -f $file ]] && mvn clean test -Dtest=$file
done
```

will run the comand on all files.  If you want to recurse into subdirectories then you need to use the `find` command

```
for file in $(find $1 -type f)
do
    etc...
done
```

Comment: What if the <directory_name> argument only gives me the name of the directory, but not the location. In other words, I know for sure the given dir is somewhere in `/.' but it could be anywhere. So should I use `for file in $(find $1 -type d)` (d for directory?) ?

Comment: And what's the meaning of `[[ -f $file]]` ?

Comment: Wrap one of the above in `for dir in $(find . -type d -name $1); do ... inner loop ... done`

Comment: That's a test to select only files and skip any subdirectories and links.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/sh
# Set IFS to newline to minimise problems with whitespace in file/directory 
# names. If we also need to deal with newlines, we will need to use
# find -print0 | xargs -0 instead of a for loop.
IFS="
"
if ! [[ -d "${1}" ]]; then
  echo "Please supply a directory name" > &2
  exit 1
else
  # We use find rather than glob expansion in case there are nested directories.
  # We sort the filenames so that we execute the tests in a predictable order.
  for pathname in $(find "${1}" -type f | LC_ALL=C sort) do
    mvn clean test -Dtest="${pathname}" || break
  done
fi
# exit $? would be superfluous (it is the default)
```